# How can I change the content of XML file with Apache Camel, java DSL, eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-camel

I have a XML file, which is named input-kunde-2.xml.

```
from("file:c:/test/?fileName=input-kunde-2.xml")
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<list>    
   <Name>Ying</Name>
   <Age>23</Age>
</list>
```

And i have used Apache Camel route this file from C:/ into another place D:/.

```
to("file:d:/test/?fileName=output-kunde-2.xml")
```

## What do I want?

Now, i want change the content of XML file.

In the file input-kunde-2.xml: `<Name>Ying</Name>`

In the file output-kunde-2.xml: `<Name>Wang</Name>`

How can I implement it?
Ich have try to use:

```
File body = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
//KundeDTO kundeDTO = exchange.getIn().getBody(KundeDTO.class);
```

But i could only get the path of the XML file.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want the content of the file try with `String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);`

Comment: You are right! I have got it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to extract values from the file, treat it as an XML document and make use of xpath

For instance with

```
.setHeader("myHeader").xpath("/list/Name/text()", String.class)
```

This documentation is here http://camel.apache.org/xpath.html

---

If you want to modify an entire XML document, then make use of XSLT. Consume your file with 'from', then pass it through the XSLT component, then send it to your file location

This documentation is here http://camel.apache.org/xslt.html